# How can i use yield in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

After receiving the result value of the refresh function, axiosInstace is executed before saving the accesstoken to AsyncStorage, so the updated token cannot be retrieved in axios.js through AsyncStorage.getItem. i want to save accesstoken first in refresh and get acecesstoken in axios.js and send to axiosInstace

How can I solve this problem?

this is my code

(saga.js)

```
    function getPostAPI(data) {
      return axiosInstace.post('/kakao/getpost', data);
    }


    function* getPost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(getPostAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: GETPOST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.response.data === 'jwtEx') {
          yield put({
            type: REFRESH_REQUEST,
            // data: action.data,
          });
          yield put({
            type: GETPOST_REQUEST,
            data: action.data,
          });
        } else {
          yield put({
            type: GETPOST_FAILURE,
            error: err.response.data,
          });
        }
      }
    }


    function refreshAPI() {
      return axiosInstace.post('/kakao/refresh');
    }

    function* refresh() {
      try {
        const result = yield call(refreshAPI);
        yield AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'accesstoken',
          `${result.data.accessToken}`,
          () => {
            // console.log('accesstoken 재발급 저장 완료');
          },
        );
        yield put({
          type: REFRESH_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        yield put({
          type: REFRESH_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }
```

(axios.js)

```
    AxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async (cfg) => {

      const acecesstoken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('accesstoken');
      const refreshtoken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('refreshtoken');

      if (acecesstoken) {
        cfg.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${acecesstoken}    ${refreshtoken}`;
      }

      return cfg;
    });

    export default AxiosInstance;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to call your `refresh()` generator directly:

```
function* getPost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(getPostAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: GETPOST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.response.data === 'jwtEx') {
          yield call(refresh);
          
          // you could also redispatch the original action
          yield put(action);
        } else {
          yield put({
            type: GETPOST_FAILURE,
            error: err.response.data,
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Alternatively your can start a race between `REFRESH_SUCCESS` and `REFRESH_FAILURE`:

```
const { success, failure } = yield race({
    success: take('REFRESH_SUCCESS'),
    failure: take('REFRESH_FAILURE'),
  });

if(success) {
  // continue
} else {
  // handle refresh failure
}
```

Comment: thank you for help it's work!!!!!! but i want to know wht your code make  error fixed?

Comment: if you call `yield put({ type: REFRESH_REQUEST})` your saga yields until the action is dispatched, but not until all effects were executed. Calling the generator directly will wait until the generator finished. Note that you should throw an error when calling `refresh()` directly  when refreshing the token fails.

Comment: you said Note that you should throw an error when calling refresh() directly when refreshing the token fails <<. Is this problem solved by using your code?

Comment: No. Your `refresh()` catches the possible exception from `refreshAPI()`. This is why the caller will not notice that the refresh failed and will continue with `yield put({ type: GETPOST_REQUEST, data: action.data})` regardless the actual result. So either throw an error from `refresh()` on failure, or use my other solution.

Comment: oh i understood what you mean ... but how can i fix my code?.... it it so difficult..

Comment: if i use your second sulution where should i put it?